# how to identify caught errors?

Tags: c#, exception

I catch `Exception`.

I would like to do something if that is a specific error. I can easily identify it with the string.

However I wondered if there is a cleaner way to do this. For example, when I create my own wrapper for exception I add an index.

Is there such a thing in default exception?

The function I use that throws errors is an instantiation of `RemoteWebDriver` (selenium object). However I don't need an answer specific for that class.

To be more precise, I catch the following error: `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException`.
However it may be thrown if there is a timeout when creating a driver or if a js file is closed. They have the save `HResult`.

So I see no way to differentiate them other than to check string unfortunately...

Comment: Do you want to catch a specific subclass of `Exception`? Or one with a specific message?

Comment: Well, pretty vague. First of all do not catch Exception but prefer more derived classes. Some of them have a numeric error code to discriminate more specific errors. Base class has HResult property too. Without more context...

Comment: You can `catch (SomeSubClassOfException)`, or in C# 6, you can use [exception filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268223/c-sharp-exception-filter).

Comment: I'd like one with a specific message.
About the subclass I use this, but more than 1 message is associated with the same subclass... so I still need to check the substring. HResult property I'll look into that thanks

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim Filtering exceptions by their message is a big design flaw in your code!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That is exactly the reason of my question, to correct this !! :P

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim Sadly if who implemented that exception thought that two completely different issues should be thrown with the same exception, you're stuck in implementing a workaround like yours.......

Comment: If you have existing code you want to change, you need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38361928/edit) your post to include the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch specific exceptions. For example...

```
try
{
    //Do things with your RemoteWebDriver...
}
catch (ImportantException e)
{
    //Do something important with this specific exception
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

This code "does" something specific when and only when an Exception of type `ImportantException` gets thrown, but in all other cases, it does something else (in this example, it just throws the exception).

You can also use exception filters as of C#6. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4268291/1672990

Comment: thanks, however I like to filter exactly one exception without having to filter the string, not sure how to do it?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim I am not sure what "string" you are referring to.

Comment: I have at least 3 errors of the same type, but the contained message is different. As of now, this is the only way I foundto differentiate them.

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - Do you have control over the creation of the exceptions such that you can edit the message and other properties of it?

Comment: @keyboardP Unfortunately I use dll (selenium web driver)

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim In that case, I would use the same method as above, but once you have caught the exception, examine the contents of its messages and react as needed.

It really needs to be stressed that changing the behavior of your program based on exception message contents in this way is  really not desirable. If a different message that you've never seen before comes up, or you update your libraries, you may have to make changes to accommodate these updates. It's usually not desirable to determine behaviors based on the contents of a string in general, as they are liable to change.