# Is it possible to force a try-catch even if exceptions are handled higher in the call stack?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

EXAMPLE - A() -> B() -> C()

C() contains a try-catch, and simply logs the exception and carries on with execution, because the `throw;` was commented out.

Therefore the try/catch in A() won't trigger.

```
public void A(){
   try{
      B();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      //something really important
   }
}


public void B(){
   try{
      throw new Exception("test");
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      Log.Error($"Error - {e.InnerException}");
      //throw;
   }

   //further code
}
```

Is there any mechanism that forces A() catch to capture ANY exception raised in the call-stack following it?

The reason I ask is I need to ensure any issues with a Payment are reported but there must be 40+ try catches in the masses of code that B(); contains!

Comment: No exception is thrown at that point in the stack, so there's nothing to catch.  The way to "force" a `catch` is to throw an exception.

Comment: Why `throw` is commented? Btw, you can use c# 7.0 [exception filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4268291/1997232) to log something.

Comment: @David the exception is thrown in the try of method B, and is caught within method B, so I understand as it wasn't re-thrown A is not aware but I was wondering if any mechanism exists to do so.

Comment: @Sinatr just for demonstration purposes :) In reality the code does some minor cleaning and continues execution, but I really want to ensure ANY 'cleaning' that has occurred notifies the calling function too (again, simplistic demonstration)

Comment: Inside of A you could create a static method that you call from inside of the catch block in B, passing the exception accross to notify it of any exceptions caught. -- edit just noticed A was not a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't catch an already handled exception unless that exception is rethrown:

```
try
{
   B();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // handle the exception

    throw; // then re-throw it.
}
```

If it is for logging purposes, you might be looking for the [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception) event, which gives you the ability to 'catch' exceptions even when they are handled.

Comment: Thanks, it's for logging purposes which is essentially me not wanting to try and find every single Exception in the potential code execution paths. 

I am glad you pointed out that event because it looks exactly like what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

## No

There is not. You will need to trust B() to do it's job and accurately report on the results.

There is no protection from B() being this either:

```
public bool B()
{
   var failed = ImportantOperation();

   if(failed) 
      // oops
      return true;
   else
      return true;
}
```

If you don't trust code, write it yourself or get a code provider you can trust.